# System is out of GPU memory Blender

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, units, filmic-blender, blenderkit, blender-osm

For easy projects, with some lights/shadows to none, some textures with maximum 4k or even 8k if there are not too many objects, rendering in Cycles, Experimental, GPU Compute, Noise Threshold set to 0.05, Samples to 256, Denoise ON, Min Samples 0 and Time Limit 0, everything works perfectly and fast.

But, I am working on a bit bigger project now. There is a room, with different lights (lamp, PC, HDRI from outside, white light (moon) from outside, some textures have also Emissions, and a fire plugin) I can't even render with 12 Samples, Denoise OFF, Noise Threshold OFF and still I get "System is out of GPU memory", I can't render anything and I don't know what to do.

I am using NVDIA Geforce RTX 4090, OptiX in system settings in blender, with the CPU turned off and only the GPU turned ON. I am writing this here because I don't think the problem is at my pc, but something else.

Thank you!

I tried to modify the settings of rendering, lower resolutions also for some textures but still same erros. I know I can do even more and lower my textures and lights a lot, but that will ruin the aspect of my project and I do not want that.

How can I solve it so I can render at least an image?

Comment: Hi. Do you have a question we can answer?

Comment: Yes, any methods to solve this issue? So i can render at least an image?

Comment: I am afraid the answer would be: make your project smaller so it fits into the memory. Now that's not very meaningful, but what else can be suggested without knowing anything about the project?  There is Simplify tab in Render settings that might help...

Comment: If the image resolution is high, the rendered image needs to be stored in memory as well and can take a lot of it, so rendering with tiles may help.

Comment: CUDA will allow shared memory pool, it will render slower, but it likely WILL render

Comment: I solved it somehow. Lowering the resolution, sample and noise threshold did not work. At some frames of the animation, the Simplify checked ON with 2048-4096 resolution worked, but not on all frames. At some frames from the animation, with lots of lights, objects etc it did't worked with Simplify turned on and with a decent resolution. 

I solved it finally by moving from GPU to CPU. I am not running out of memory anymore, I kept my original render settings, but of course, the rendering time is very very slow. But this is how I solved it

Comment: The memory consumption was around 25 gb. My GPU has 8GB and, of course, GPU ran out of memory. Switching on CPU which uses the RAM where I have 32gb did the job, but very very slowly, almost 3 days of rendering.

                                   (Small correction at *Lowering the resolution, sample and noise threshold
*Lowering the resolution, sample and rising noise threshold, unchecking Denoise)